# SQLite PATH environment variable & db browser sqlite

Tags: database, windows, sqlite

I’m a Java engineer (in training).  Recently started getting into databases and all involved: SQL, JDBC, MySQL & SQLite.

My questions are in regards to SQLite:

[According to tutorials point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_installation.htm), I have 4 steps in installing SQLite:

> Install SQLite On Windows:
>
> 1. Go to SQLite download page, and download precompiled binaries from Windows section.
> 2. You will need to download sqlite-shell-win32-*.zip and sqlite-dll-win32-*.zip zipped files.
> 3. Create a folder C:>sqlite and unzip above two zipped files in this folder which will give you sqlite3.def, sqlite3.dll and sqlite3.exe
>      files.
> 4. Add C:>sqlite in your PATH environment variable and finally go to the command prompt and issue sqlite3 command, which should display a
>      result something as below.

I’m not sure what to make of step 4.

Most of the SQLite tutorials I have found simply DL the shell, place it in a folder in C and then access SQLite3 via command, & then start working.

I’ve done all of this, made a DB and work with it a bit, etc…

I also put a shortcut to the SQLite shell on my desktop.

Question: what is sqlite-dll-win32-*.zip for?

Question: How should I go about(do I need to) Add C:>sqlite in your PATH environment variable?

I’ve also been learning how to use db browser sqlite.

Qestion: I’m wondering if when I DL & installed this(sqlitebrowser) if some of the above was taken care of/installed with?  And if you can recommend any tutorials for it(or SQLite for that matter)?

I’ve set environment variable before(but limited experience).
Here is a pic of my system properties & the value of my Path variable…if this helps in some way.

http://screencast.com/t/mbpfEMw8

BTW: Windows 8.1, 64x. & thanks.

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.3 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.3 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.3 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.3 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\
```

Comment: Please ask separate questions separately.

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable comes into play when easily accessing an executable. This has nothing to do with sqlite. It is a general operating system thing. You can google for that.

Comment: @arkascha is this why when after I download sqlite and extract the sqlite3.exe to the sqlite3 directory i create inside my c drive, that I cannot create a db from the command prompt in any other directory(for example my Desktop directory).

Answer (score 8):

I will answer to your step 4: Add C:>sqlite in your PATH environment variable

1. First go to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables
2. Double click the "Path" item from User variables.
3. Click on "New" from the right side bar.
4. Generally, it should be C:\sqlite
5. Save it.

You have successfully added path variable for your SQLite.